do subkeys on other devices needs to be re-issued and imported again after changing secret passphrase?
I need to change the passphrase initially set for my gpg key to a new one. I have three devices/hosts that each have their own signing subkey issued from the master, and a shared encrypt subkey used by all three devices.
After re-importing the previously deleted (from keyring) secret/private key and changing the passphrase, will the subkeys need to be re-issued and imported again by the other two devices?
I imagine they would need to be re-imported, but since I am no gpg guru I thought I would ask first and act after. Thanks.

Passphrases are a local matter – they are only used for encrypting the files containing the key data, but they have absolutely no effect on the actual key material. You can independently change the passphrase on each copy of your PGP keys to the same one, or you can have the copies encrypted with different passphrases; it doesn't change the way it will function.

Ok that's interesting and makes sense, if I understand you correctly. I could change the passphrase on just one host/device, and thesub-keys on the other two devices would (obviously it seems) remain unchanged, unless I either changed them locally on their respective devices, or I deleted the sub-keys on those other two devs and re-issued them again from the master with which the passphrase has been changed?

Yes, they don't really have a communication channel after all, so the change only applies to the individual copy. If you export the key from one system, though, IIRC the export process actually re-encrypts it (i.e. it asks for the old passphrase of the stored key and then for the new passphrase of the exported key).
